# how to make password textbox value visible when hover an icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good day all,

I have a form that has a password field:

```
<input type="password" name="password" size="30" />
```

Naturally, the input text will be replaced by (*).

So if the user typed `123` the box will show `***`.

Up to here, it is straight forward, but...

Now, I wanna add a small icon next to the password box so when the user hover over this icon, he can see what he has entered so far.

So, while hovering, the box will show `123` and when the user leaves the icon the box should show `***` again.

Is there any way to do this with JavaScript? Also, I am using HTML and PHP.

**EDIT:**

**It really doesn't need to be an icon, it could be a checkbox or a button... AND if it could be done in CSS, I would really appreciate to know how**

*P.S. I've googled and search the stackoverflow but with no luck*

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You will need to get the textbox via javascript when moving the mouse over it and change its `type` to `text`. And when moving it out, you will want to change it back to `password`. No chance of doing this in pure CSS.

HTML:

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="myPassword" size="30" />
<img src="theicon" onmouseover="mouseoverPass();" onmouseout="mouseoutPass();" />
```

JS:

```
function mouseoverPass() {
  let obj = document.getElementById('myPassword');
  obj.type = 'text';
}
function mouseoutPass() {
  let obj = document.getElementById('myPassword');
  obj.type = 'password';
}
```

Comment: it worked fine in chrome and Firefox but not on IE.. I've IE 10

Comment: This is working fine with IE 10, I turned off the compatibility View.  What about old IEs?

Comment: This is pretty basic and low level javascript so this should be compatible to very old browsers.

Answer (score 17):

As these guys said, just change input type.
But do not forget to change type back as well.

See my simple jquery demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kPJbU/1/

HTML:

```
<input name="password" class="password" type="password" />
<div class="icon">icon</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.icon').hover(function () {
    $('.password').attr('type', 'text');
}, function () {
    $('.password').attr('type', 'password');
});
```

Answer (score 11):

I use this one line of code, it should do it:

```
<input type="password"
       onmousedown="this.type='text'"
       onmouseup="this.type='password'"
       onmousemove="this.type='password'">
```

Comment: It should be `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`.

Answer (score 10):

Complete example below. I just love the copy/paste :)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
           <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" method="" action="">

                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Email</label>
                           <div class="col-md-6">
                               <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="">
                           </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <input id="password-field" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="secret">
                              <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-lg fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                 </form>
              </div>
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.field-icon {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-top: -23px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.container{
  padding-top:50px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".toggle-password").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
   var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
   if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
     input.attr("type", "text");
   } else {
     input.attr("type", "password");
   }
});
```

Try it here: https://codepen.io/Loginet/pen/oNeevMe

Comment: just simple and executable, i like it.

Answer (score 6):

In one line of code as below :

```html
<p> cursor on text field shows text .if not password will be shown</p>
<input type="password" name="txt_password" onmouseover="this.type='text'"
       onmouseout="this.type='password'" placeholder="password" />
```

Comment: Move the mouse pointer across the editbox in a certain speed that the browser generate the onmouseover event but don't have enough time to generate the onmouseout and see that it remains in plain text mode.

Answer (score 3):

1 minute googling gave me [this result](http://www.mburnette.com/blog/toggle-password-field-text-visibility). See the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WJ4kR/)**!

HTML

```
<form>
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

jQuery

```js
// ----- Setup: Add dummy text field for password and add toggle link to form; "offPage" class moves element off-screen
$('input[type=password]').each(function () {
    var el = $(this),
        elPH = el.attr("placeholder");
    el.addClass("offPage").after('<input class="passText" placeholder="' + elPH + '" type="text" />');
});
$('form').append('<small><a class="togglePassText" href="#">Toggle Password Visibility</a></small>');

// ----- keep password field and dummy text field in sync
$('input[type=password]').keyup(function () {
    var elText = $(this).val();
    $('.passText').val(elText);
});
$('.passText').keyup(function () {
    var elText = $(this).val();
    $('input[type=password]').val(elText);
});

// ----- Toggle link functionality - turn on/off "offPage" class on fields
$('a.togglePassText').click(function (e) {
    $('input[type=password], .passText').toggleClass("offPage");
    e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent any default actions
});
```

CSS

```css
.offPage {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    right: 100%;
}
```

Comment: what phrase did you use for searching?

Comment: input type password visible

Comment: Why in Odin's name does one get jQuery mumble jumble when the question clearly addresses plain and clean JavaScript for an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try This :

In HTML and JS :

```js
// Convert Password Field To Text On Hover.
  var passField = $('input[type=password]');
  $('.show-pass').hover(function() {
      passField.attr('type', 'text');
  }, function() {
    passField.attr('type', 'password');
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- An Input PassWord Field With Eye Font-Awesome Class -->
<input type="password" placeholder="Type Password">
      <i class="show-pass fa fa-eye fa-lg"></i>
```

Comment: it should be noted that you are coding in jquery not javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple javascript. Done using toggling the `type` attribute of the input. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/RZm5y/16/

Answer (score 1):

```
   <script>
       function seetext(x){
           x.type = "text";
       }
       function seeasterisk(x){
          x.type = "password";
       }
   </script>
  <body>
    <img onmouseover="seetext(a)" onmouseout="seeasterisk(a)" border="0" src="smiley.gif"   alt="Smiley" width="32" height="32">
   <input id = "a" type = "password"/>
 </body>
```

Try this see if it works

Comment: only works if you set `var a = document.getElementById('a');` globally before

Answer (score 1):

A rapid response not tested on several browsers,
works on gg chrome / win +edit: ok on Linux/Brave

-> On focus event -> show/hide password

```
<input type="password" name="password">
```

script jQuery

```
// show on focus
$('input[type="password"]').on('focusin', function(){

    $(this).attr('type', 'text');

});
// hide on focus Out
$('input[type="password"]').on('focusout', function(){

    $(this).attr('type', 'password');

});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function demo(){
    var d=document.getElementById('s1');
    var e=document.getElementById('show_f').value;
    var f=document.getElementById('show_f').type; 

    if(d.value=="show"){
        var f= document.getElementById('show_f').type="text";
        var g=document.getElementById('show_f').value=e;
        d.value="Hide";

    } else{
        var f= document.getElementById('show_f').type="password";
        var g=document.getElementById('show_f').value=e;
        d.value="show";
     }     
  }   
</script>   

<form method='post'>
Password: <input type='password' name='pass_f' maxlength='30' id='show_f'><input type="button" onclick="demo()" id="s1" value="show" style="height:25px; margin-left:5px;margin-top:3px;"><br><br>
<input type='submit' name='sub' value='Submit Now'>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```