# WebApplication ASP.Net C#. Unmasking a textbox also known as show password

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, textbox

I'm trying to make a 'show password' checkbox underneath my textbox-Password to unmask the txtpassword and show the characters.

```
protected void chkUnmask_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkUnmask.Checked == true)
        {
            txtPassword.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Password;
        }
        else
        {
            txtPassword.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Password;
        }
    }
```

I use If-Else condition to change the behavior of the textbox everytime the checkbox change to checked and unchecked. It works fine with WindowsFormApp C#, but in WebApp C# ASP.net doesn't, I tried to restart the visual studio and my laptop hoping it's just a bug but still doesn't work.. I wonder if my coding was wrong.

Comment: If you don't want to mask them, why are you setting to `TextBoxMode.Password`?

Comment: Please see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22480075/how-to-make-password-textbox-value-visible-when-hover-an-icon

Comment: I changed it to..
`txtPassword.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;` 
when checked is true. but still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

How would the result be different if both if conditions are

```
txtPassword.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Password;
    }
  You need to change the TextBox mode for one of the conditions 

// I think you need to set break points and check if this line is being triggered
TextBox1.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;

// you can try this code which works fine. Add a button, and a textbox and set its textmode to Password. Type something the then click the button. 
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
}
```

Comment: oh.. YEAH! right, dammit didn't notice, myBad.. I'll delete this posted-question in a minute.

Comment: nope. Still not working :( I use this code when checked was true.

`txtPassword.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;`

Comment: What happens when you change the mode?  Is the text disappearing or staying *******